# How to set a var to true or false using .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox, I need to check if the textbox is empty and set a variable accordingly to true or false.

my code at the moment print the value of the textbox.

```
var isDateTimEndEmpty = dateTimeEnd.val() == null ? true : false;
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Anything of the form `x ? true : false` shows a failure to understand simple concepts...

Comment: Try using ( ), this should help

Comment: `a == b` already evaluates to a boolean, meaning its value is already either `true` or `false`. As it currently reads, your code is therefore saying 'if `x` is true, yield true, if `x` is false, yield false'...where you could obviously get the same result by just saying 'yield `x`'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct way:

```
var isDateTimEndEmpty = !$.trim(dateTimeEnd.val()).length;
```

Good practice is to use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) which makes the code to ignore spaces in the input field. So if the length of *trimmed* value is `0` then the value is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Check its length

```
var isDateTimeEndEmpty = $.trim($('#txtboxID').val()).length > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

the result of `dateTimeEnd.val()` won't be null. it always a string, might be empty string.

in actually, you don't need to get a 'true' of 'false', just a "truly" or "falsy" value, like empty or non-empty string:

```
var isDateTimEndEmpty = $.trim(dateTimeEnd.val()) //remove spaces at start and end
if (isDateTimEndEmpty) {
    //if dataTimeEnd is not empty, go here
} else {
    //if dateTimeEnd is empty, go here
}
```

if you were uncomfortable with the implicit casting, you can code it in explicit way as well:

```
var isDateTimEndEmpty = Boolean($.trim(dateTimeEnd.val())); //explicit casting
```